# Robospice: How to enable the FULL loggin level?

Tags: android, robospice

I have a simple app on android that make request to an API REST, but when I try to obtain the response object from Robospice Listener, it is null. I know, I could fix it, but I dont know how debug the server response, I need to get the String response to print out to Android Log and continue debugging.

I am using the retrofit plugin with robospice, I have a POJO object called Vendor, and I set up all the configuration specified in the documentation, the request, the Service, the listener, the onStart() onStop() activity code, all, and It works, but fail in the parse step.

The closest I came to get the answer was to enable bug reports from retrofit

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
    .setEndpoint("https://api.github.com")
    .build();
```

but I do not know how to get an instance of retrofit in robospice to configure LogLevel.FULL

Is there any way to activate the full Log? Or is there another way to debug requests and see the chain as it comes from the server?

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding [`RetrofitSpiceService#createRestAdapterBuilder`](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/blob/release/extensions/robospice-retrofit-parent/robospice-retrofit/src/main/java/com/octo/android/robospice/retrofit/RetrofitSpiceService.java#L34).